# Twilio Client identification for App to App Voip call

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am implementing an app to app voice call using Twilio VoIP.
Going through the documentation, I am able to make calls between phone numbers using Twilio.

To make calls between two devices without using phone numbers, Twilio document suggested to use the client identifier.

How to create the client identifier ? Does Twilio stores the client identifier ?

I tried calls between two phone numbers via Twiliio. Next, I am trying make app to app call using Twilio but I am not clear how Twilio identifies the two devices/clients

Answer (score 0):

To create a client identifier, you need an Access Token. For example, to create an [Access Token for the Voice SDK in Python](https://www.twilio.com/docs/iam/access-tokens?code-sample=code-create-an-access-token-for-the-voice-sdks&code-language=Python&code-sdk-version=7.x):

```
import os
from twilio.jwt.access_token import AccessToken
from twilio.jwt.access_token.grants import VoiceGrant

# required for all twilio access tokens
# To set up environmental variables, see http://twil.io/secure
account_sid = os.environ['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID']
api_key = os.environ['TWILIO_API_KEY']
api_secret = os.environ['TWILIO_API_KEY_SECRET']

# required for Voice grant
outgoing_application_sid = 'APxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
identity = 'user'

# Create access token with credentials
token = AccessToken(account_sid, api_key, api_secret, identity=identity)

# Create a Voice grant and add to token
voice_grant = VoiceGrant(
    outgoing_application_sid=outgoing_application_sid,
    incoming_allow=True, # Optional: add to allow incoming calls
)
token.add_grant(voice_grant)

# Return token info as JSON
print(token.to_jwt())
```

In this example, the `identity` will be associated to the Access Token.
Then, when you make the Voice call, the `To or From` parameter should be in the form `client:name_of_identity`.